# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) after deployment

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-2.0

I am facing one issue with my Jquery ajax call. I am working on asp.net application. I am returning a string Array of JSON string. In my local system its working fine but after deployment its throwing this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

```
function RenderUserPerosnaDashboard() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UserPersonaDashBoard.aspx/RenderUserPerosnaDashboard",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        //Brute Force Attack User Prospective Chart Rendering Method
        var BFDeviceChartObj = JSON.parse(data.d[0]);
        setSuspiciusUserBruteForceChart(BFDeviceChartObj);
        //Brute Force Attack Device Prospective Chart Rendering Code
        var BFUserChartObj = JSON.parse(data.d[1]);
        setDeviceUseBruteForceChart(BFUserChartObj);

        setSuspiciusUserAccessBehaviorAnamolyChart();
        setSuspiciusDeviceAccessBehaviorAnamolyChart();
        setSuspiciusAccountCreatedChart();
        setAccountCreatedMonthChart();
        InitializeModalPopUp();
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Server Side Code

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string[] RenderUserPerosnaDashboard()
    {

        string[] jsonArray = new string[2];
        jsonArray[0] = DashboardHelper.GetSuspiciousUserAccountsBruteForce();
        jsonArray[1] = DashboardHelper.GetSuspiciousDeviceBruteForce();
        return jsonArray;

    }
```

One more information I had encountered the same issue in Local system as well but after adding below configuration in Web config file its got resolved.

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

Please help me.

Comment: is web method placed in UserPersonaDashBoard.aspx.cs

Comment: yes its working fine in my local system but after deployment its throwing this error.

Comment: does turning on compilation debug mode inside of web.config show you anymore information?